# In Server side Blazor app authorization based on Roles is not working

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I have been trying to learn Blazor identity service. But in the app the Roles tag does not work. Here is my Blazor page

```
            <AuthorizeView Roles="Admin" Context="adminContext">
                <Authorized>
                    <GridColumn Width="70px">
                        <Template>
                            @{
                                Contact contact = context as Contact;
                                <TelerikButton OnClick="@( e => EditContact(e, contact.ContactId) )">Edit</TelerikButton>
                            }
                        </Template>
                    </GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Width="90px">
                        <Template>
                            @{
                                Contact contact = context as Contact;
                                <TelerikButton OnClick="@( e => DeleteContact(e, contact.ContactId) )">Delete</TelerikButton>
                            }
                        </Template>
                    </GridColumn>
                </Authorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
```

My startup class ConfigureServices method looks like this. I have inherited IdentityRole and have created my own class called ApplicationRole. I have also overwritten various stores as seen in the code below. Same way I have also inherited IdentityUser and have created ApplicationUser

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
                .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>();
```

```
    public class ApplicationRoleStore : IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUserRole>, IQueryableRoleStore<ApplicationRole>
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;


    public class ApplicationUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>, IQueryableUserStore<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
```

Comment: Do u find solution?